# Stop Modal from closing when AngularJS gets update to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a web application that polls a server for data updates (based on a queue of tests being run on the server). I have a bootstrap-modal containing a log if a test fails. When the application receives an update from the server, any open modal is closed but the page is left with the modal screen preventing interaction.

I have tried pausing updates when a modal is opened and resuming them when it is closed, but that doesn't seem to have fixed the problem. I have also tried moving the modals for logs to sit directly under  in the DOM. It seems the data changing causes the page to redraw everything inside the controller.

excerpt from index.html

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="testStatusController as testStatus">
    Header Row (static html)
                <div class="row test-table-data {{script.colorClass}}" ng-repeat="script in testStatus.scripts">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p class="align-middle"><span class="d-inline d-md-none">Name: </span><span>{{script.tcName}}</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 align-middle">
                        <p><span class="d-inline d-md-none">Description: </span>{{script.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-md-2 align-middle">
                        <p><span class="d-inline d-md-none">Run Status: </span>{{script.status}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-md-2">
                        <p>
                            <span class="icon text-align-middle dripicons-wrong text-danger big" ng-if="!script.pass && script.status=='Complete'" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".{{script.tcName.slice(0,-4)}}"></span>
                            <span class="d-inline icon dripicons-checkmark text-success big" ng-if="script.pass"></span>
                            <span class="spinner-border text-primary" ng-if="script.status=='Running'"></span>
                            <span class="d-inline icon dripicons-clock text-primary big" ng-if="script.status=='Not Run'"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal fade {{script.tcName.slice(0,-4)}} log" ng-if="!script.pass && script.status == 'Complete'">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" ng-focus="testStatus.pauseUpdates(true)" ng-blur="testStatus.pauseUpdates(false)">
                            <div class="modal-content log-modal">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <div class="modal-title text-monospace">
                                        <h4>{{script.tcName}}</h4>
                                        <h6>{{script.description}}</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p class="text-monospace"><span ng-repeat="log in testStatus.getLog(script.tcName).lines track by $index">{{log.line}}<br /></span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row test-table-foot">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p>Passed: <span>{{testStatus.passed()}}</span></p>
                   </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p>Failed: <span>{{testStatus.failed()}}</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p>Remaining: <span>{{testStatus.remaining()}}</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p>Total: <span>{{testStatus.total()}}</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

the update Function (in main.js called every 5 seconds) Comments indicate what code was removed to help keep things brief.

```
testList.updateResults = function () { 
            if (testList.running) {
                $http({url:theUrl + "?cmd=json&testRun=default", 
                        method: "GET"
                    }).then(function(response){
                        var strRes = response.data.result;
                        var tmp = angular.fromJson(strRes);
                        // update trName if bound input not focused
                        testList.scripts = tmp.tc;
                        testList.running = false;
                        angular.forEach(tmp.tc, function(script, index){
                            if(script.status != "Complete") {
                                testList.running = true;
                                script.colorClass = "text-primary";
                            }
                            else {
                                if(script.pass) {
                                    script.colorClass = "text-success";
                                }
                                else {
                                    script.colorClass = "text-danger";
                                    if(!(script.tcName.slice(0, -4) in testList.logs)) {
                                        testList.getLog(script.tcName);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        // update start/stop button
                    }, function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    });
            }
        };
```

I would expect that AngularJS would not update sections of the DOM if the data bound to them was the same, but instead everything in the controller section is redrawn. My next instinct was to separate the logs and the status into different controllers, but I suspect I will have the same problem when a new log gets appended to the list of logs.

Comment: what is modal screen preventing interaction?

Comment: you have an ng-if on the modal div, that could be the reason your modal is disappearing after you get the update from the server

Comment: the ng-if is there to only put the modal in the dom if the log is supposed to exist. It checks if the test failed and it's done running. Since the server deletes the log if a test passes, we don't have a log to populate the modal in that case.

Comment: in addition, semantically, once the modal enters the DOM, the data that put it there is static, so there shouldn't be a reason to update it.

Comment: how is your data static if you are calling your server every 5 seconds? and what does your servers returns if the test passes?

Comment: I said semantically, because once a test is complete, the object associated with that test is always the same, despite the fact that it is updated every 5 seconds (because we need to know the status of any tests that are yet to run). We don't call for a log unless the test fails.